# Filtering out records based on a related record's attribute

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I Have a LINQ query like so:

```
from a in _context.tblTradeSpends
orderby a.DealPeriod, a.CustomerNumber, a.LOB, a.VersionDate descending
select new
{
  DealPeriod = a.DealPeriod,
  CustomerNumber = a.CustomerNumber,
  LOB = a.LOB,
  PromoID = a.PromoID,
  VersionDate = a.VersionDate
}
```

Here is a small sample from my resultset (sorry for the formatting):

```
DealPeriod  CustomerNumber   LOB    PromoID     VersionDate

2013        10001            PL     P0083312    12/04/2013 9:05
2013        10001            PL     P0083313    12/04/2013 9:05
2013        10001            PL     P0083314    12/04/2013 9:05
2013        10001            PL     P0085100    12/04/2013 9:05
2013        10001            PL     P0086169    12/04/2013 9:05
2013        10001            PL     P0083312    18/01/2013 10:51
2013        10001            PL     P0083313    18/01/2013 10:51
2013        10001            PL     P0083314    18/01/2013 10:51
2013        10001            PL     P0085100    18/01/2013 10:51
2013        10001            PL     P0083312    07/07/2013 15:41
2013        10001            PL     P0083313    07/07/2013 15:41
2013        10001            PL     P0083314    07/07/2013 15:41
2013        10001            SCF    P0083308    03/05/2013 11:27
2013        10001            SCF    P0083309    03/05/2013 11:27
2013        10001            SCF    P0085088    03/05/2013 11:27
2013        10001            SCF    P0085380    03/05/2013 11:27
2013        10001            SCF    P0085381    03/05/2013 11:27
2013        10213            SCF    P0086880    11/07/2013 20:23
2013        10213            SCF    P0086881    11/07/2013 20:23
2013        10213            SCF    P0086882    11/07/2013 20:23
2013        10213            SCF    P0086883    11/07/2013 20:23
2013        10213            SCF    P0083630    28/05/2013 13:38
2013        10213            SCF    P0083631    28/05/2013 13:38
2013        10213            SCF    P0083632    28/05/2013 13:38
2013        10213            SCF    P0083633    28/05/2013 13:38
```

I need to analyze this data, so I'm looking to remove certain related records in order to trim things down. My rule is that I would like to remove all records that have the same Deal Period, Customer Number, and LOB fields where none of them have a version date past 1/6/2013 (June 1, 2013)

So, in my resultset, I would like to keep all records beginning with `2013|10001|PL` as some records have a version date 07/17/2013

I would to remove the records beginning with `2013|10001|SCF` because no records with those field values have a version date past 1/6/2013

I would like to keep the records beginning with `2013|10213|SCF` because some of those records have a version date of 11/07/2013.

*EDIT*

I attempted King King's code, and I got some related records which should not be in there. Here are two groups which I would have been filtered out:

```
2013    10039   SCF P0083145    05/02/2013 10:22
2013    10039   SCF P0083146    05/02/2013 10:22
2013    10039   SCF P0083147    05/02/2013 10:22
2013    10039   SCF P0085152    05/02/2013 10:22
2013    10039   SCF P0083145    1/22/2013 5:55:00 PM
2013    10039   SCF P0083146    1/22/2013 5:55:00 PM
2013    10039   SCF P0083147    1/22/2013 5:55:00 PM
2013    10039   SCF P0085152    1/22/2013 5:55:00 PM
2013    10039   SCF P0083145    12/05/2012 19:21
2013    10039   SCF P0083146    12/05/2012 19:21
2013    10039   SCF P0083147    12/05/2012 19:21
2013    10040   PL  P0084345    1/14/2013 10:27:00 AM
2013    10040   PL  P0084346    1/14/2013 10:27:00 AM
2013    10040   PL  P0084347    1/14/2013 10:27:00 AM
2013    10040   PL  P0084348    1/14/2013 10:27:00 AM
2013    10040   PL  P0084345    12/20/2012 10:15:00 PM
2013    10040   PL  P0084346    12/20/2012 10:15:00 PM
2013    10040   PL  P0084347    12/20/2012 10:15:00 PM
2013    10040   PL  P0084348    12/20/2012 10:15:00 PM
```

Comment: have you tried my newly edited code?

Comment: What result should be excluded? All the entries in your edit should be what you want as I understand.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but all the records I identified above should be excluded, as none of them have a version date later than June 1, 2013. Publishing code to build server now, stand by, thanks!

Comment: No, still no success, I am still getting the group of records beginning with `2013|10039|SCF`, even though not a single record has a VersionDate later than June 1, 2013. We've had a data integrity issue after June 1, 2013, if that helps explain the need, and those three attributes define a "Version" - i didn't come up with this architecture!

Comment: I've just edited my code, please try checking if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep pulling in groups of records where none in the group are later than June 1, 2013. Is your "<=" operator between VersionDate and fixedDate supposed to be that? And should we be using All() instead of Any()?

Comment: Yes, BTW, you should notice the culture/DateTime format. I suppose the `DateTime.Parse("6/1/2013")` will hold the date `June 1st 2013`, you should check this on your side.

Comment: Yes, I edited the Date to my culture.

Comment: If so the `fixedDate` should be `DateTime.Parse("1/6/2013")`. I've tested the code and posted the result in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fixedDate = DateTime.Parse("6/1/2013");
var result = _context.tblTradeSpends.GroupBy(x=>new {x.DealPeriod, x.CustomerNumber, x.LOB})     
                                    .Where(g=>g.All(x=>x.VersionDate <= fixedDate) || g.Count()==1)
                                    .SelectMany(g=>g);
```

I believe this code should work so I've tried creating a sample list as given by the OP's example and tested the code, here is the result:

```
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083312 : 4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083313 : 4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083314 : 4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0085100 : 4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0086169 : 4/12/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083312 : 1/18/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083313 : 1/18/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083314 : 1/18/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0085100 : 1/18/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083312 : 12/7/2012 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083313 : 12/7/2012 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : PL : P0083314 : 12/7/2012 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : SCF : P0083308 : 5/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : SCF : P0083309 : 5/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : SCF : P0085088 : 5/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : SCF : P0085380 : 5/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
2013 : 1001 : SCF : P0085381 : 5/3/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

As far as I understand the OP's requirement, this list should be what the OP wants (after removing all the unwanted entries).

Comment: I get "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @ChrisHardie you should declare some variable outside the query to hold the value of `6/1/2013`

Comment: Never mind, i just parsed the string outside the query and it seems to work.

Comment: @ChrisHardie my answer was edited, have you tried it? any success?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a where clause with these conditions;

```
from a in _context.tblTradeSpends
where a.DealPeriod != 2013 && a.CutomerNumber != 10001 && a.LOB != SCF
orderby a.DealPeriod, a.CustomerNumber, a.LOB, a.VersionDate descending
select new
{
    DealPeriod = a.DealPeriod,
    CustomerNumber = a.CustomerNumber,
    LOB = a.LOB,
    PromoID = a.PromoID,
    VersionDate = a.VersionDate
}
```

The where clause will filter out all records beginning with `2013|10001|SCF`.

Comment: No, I want those records removed because none of those records with those values have a VersionDate after June 1, 2013. I have many other combinations that I want removed besides 2013|10001|SCF.

Comment: @ChrisHardie that's what this will do. The where is three conjunctively bound conditions, notice they're all using `!=` which is not equal to. So it will give you everything but those records. Since we're only removing 1 of three classifications of records it's simplest to filter out what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should create a generic comparer for anonymous types:

```
public class MyEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    Func<T, T, bool> _equalsFunction;
    Func<T, int> _hashCodeFunction;

    public MyEqualityComparer(
        Func<T, T, bool> equalsFunction, Func<T, int> hashCodeFunction)
    {
        if (equalsFunction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (hashCodeFunction == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _equalsFunction = equalsFunction;
        _hashCodeFunction = hashCodeFunction;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _equalsFunction(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return _hashCodeFunction(obj);
    }
}
```

Then, use the following query:

```
var comp = new MyEqualityComparer<tblTradeSpend>(
            (x, y) => x.DealPeriod == y.DealPeriod && 
                x.CustomerNumber == y.CustomerNumber && 
                x.LOB == y.LOB, 
            obj => obj.DealPeriod.GetHashCode() ^ 
                 obj.CustomerNumber.GetHashCode() ^ 
                 obj.LOB.GetHashCode()
        );    

var q = (from a in _context.tblTradeSpends.AsEnumerable()
    where a.VersionDate < DateTime.Parse("6/1/2013")        
    select new
    {
        DealPeriod = a.DealPeriod,
        CustomerNumber = a.CustomerNumber,
        LOB = a.LOB,
        PromoID = a.PromoID,
        VersionDate = a.VersionDate
    }).Distinct(comp).OrderBy(o => o.DealPeriod)
                                 .ThenByDescending(o => o.CustomerNumber)
                                 .ThenByDescending(o => o.LOB)
                                 .ThenByDescending(o => o.PromoID).ToList();
```

Comment: Distinct() won't take your MyComparer, as it is expecting IEqualityComparer<`a>, not IEqualityComparer<DataRow>

Comment: Thanks, but based on your where filter, I don't believe your query will return a record if its version date is before June 1, 2013. Some records before then do need to be returned, but only if those records have related records that have a VersionDate that is later than June 1, 2013. Does that make sense? I know my ask is complicated.

Comment: @ChrisHardie - In fact, the main problem here is ambiguity of your question for me. Never mind, It's very late here(Iran) and I'm tired. I'll work it tomorrow and let you know abut the final working answer